# Display of individually positioned UserForm jumps when called

Tags: excel, vba

In my Excel spreadsheet I use the below VBA codes to get a UserForm as a ComboBox with the values Q1, Q2, Q3 and Q4.

---

VBA code to call **UserForm1** (connected to a button on the spreadsheet):

```
Sub Test()
Call UserForm1.Show(vbModeless)
End Sub
```

VBA code of **UserForm1**:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
Me.Top = 200
Me.Left = 800
ComboBox1.List = Array("Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4")
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Unload UserForm1
End Sub
```

---

As you can see in my code I want to poistion the **UserForm** on my spreadsheet. 
Therefore, I use the `me.Top` and `me.Left`.

When I click on the button to call the **UserForm1** Excel first places the **UserForm** on its **default** position for a **mini-second** and after that it goes on the position that I defined with the `me.` in my code.

How can I avoid this jump from the default position to the defined position?

Comment: try turning off the screen updating like so: `Sub Test()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Call UserForm1.Show(vbModeless)
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub`

Comment: I tried it but it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set the default position in the userform properties, rather than re-assigning a position on userform load.